# How to disable PHP's exec function for printing to the shell?

Tags: php, exec

I have the following php code:

```
exec('curl -X POST http://mysite.com', $output =array());
```

The return string my http://mysite.com is not displayed on the shell, but the following string is displayed:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     3    0     3    0     0     19      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

I don't want anything to display on the shell. How to I disable priting to the shell when using exec() command. There are other commands?

Answer (score 8):

Use curl's silent option: -s

```
exec('curl -s http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php', $output);
```

Comment: I don't think the OP's question is about PHP's error messages. It's about getting CURL's output but without the transfer info.

Answer (score 7):

The **stdout** stream output is captured by the php [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function. However, the **stderr** stream is not, thus the reason why some things appear on screen and others don't.

In this case this happens because`curl` is outputting status info on the `stderr` stream.

Solutions:

- Redirect **stderr** to the *null device* appending `2>/dev/null` to the command executed by `exec()` (`2> nul` in Windows). This will dispose of any messages sent to *stderr*.
- Or redirect the **stderr** stream to **stdout** by appending `2>&1` instead. This will allow capturing both outputs with `exec()` in case you need them in your php script.

For the particular case in the question, though, using [curl's silent option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3631124/4257747) may make more sense. :P